# call Python method if it exists

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.x

How to call a subclass method from a base class method, only if the subclass supports that method? And what's the best way to do that? Illustrative example, I have an animal that protects my house: if someone walks by it will look angry, and it will bark if it can.

Example code:

```
class Protector(object):
    def protect(self):
        self.lookangry()
        if hasattr(self, 'bark'):
            self.bark()

class GermanShepherd(Protector):
    def lookangry(self):
        print u') _ _ __/°°¬'
    def bark(self):
        print 'wau wau'

class ScaryCat(Protector):
    def lookangry(self):
        print '=^..^='
```

I can think of lots of alternative implementations for this:

1. Using `hasattr` as above.
2. `try: self.bark() except AttributeError: pass` but that also catches any AttributeErrors in `bark`
3. Same as 2 but inspect the error message to make sure it's the right AttributeError
4. Like 2 but define an abstract bark method that raises `NotImplementedError` in the abstract class and check for `NotImplementedError` instead of `AttributeError`. With this solution Pylint will complain that I forgot to override the abstract method in `ScaryCat`.
5. Define an empty bark method in the abstract class:

   ```
   class Protector(object):
       def protect(self):
           self.lookangry()
           self.bark()
       def bark(self):
           pass
   ```

I figured in Python their should usually be one way to do something. In this case it's not clear to me which. Which one of these options is most readable, least likely to introduce a bug when stuff is changed and most inline with coding standards, especially Pylint? Is there a better way to do it that I've missed?

Comment: I think a realistic answer to this problem needs a realistic use case—or maybe even more than one. Half the problems with OO design come from everyone in the 90s talking about Vehicle/Car/Truck/Boat, Animal/Cat/Dog/Bird, and Shape/Rectangle/Square/Circle problems, but nobody ever wrote any actual code modeling those classes. (Except the last one—and people who _did_ write that code knew that the silly Square/Rectangle problem was just about whether your application's Rectangles are mutable.)

Comment: I think the answers do just fine in pointing out all the advantages and disadvantages for different use cases. I elected not to describe my use case because it's pretty complex. I'm fitting different functions to a time series. Each function has a class. The problem doesn't even concern the fit but only the display. My `lookangry` is plotting each function on top of the time series. My `bark` is adding some annotation which I only need when displaying the step function.

I think super is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 6.) could be that the `Protector` class makes just the basic shared methods abstract thus required, while leaving the extra methods to its heirs. Of course this can be splitted into more sub-classes, see https://repl.it/repls/AridScrawnyCoderesource (Written in Python 3.6)

```
class Protector(object):
  def lookangry(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("If it can't look angry, it can't protect")

  def protect(self):
      self.lookangry()


class Doggo(Protector):
  def bark(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("If a dog can't bark, it can't protect")

  def protect(self):
    super().protect()
    self.bark()


class GermanShepherd(Doggo):

  def lookangry(self):
    print(') _ _ __/°°¬')

  def bark(self):
    print('wau wau')


class Pug(Doggo):
  # We will not consider that screeching as barking so no bark method
  def lookangry(self):
    print('(◉ω◉)')


class ScaryCat(Protector):
  def lookangry(self):
      print('o(≧o≦)o')


class Kitten(Protector):
  pass


doggo = GermanShepherd()
doggo.protect()

try:
  gleam_of_silver = Pug()
  gleam_of_silver.protect()
except NotImplementedError as e:
  print(e)

cheezburger = ScaryCat()
cheezburger.protect()

try:
  ball_of_wool = Kitten()
  ball_of_wool.protect()
except NotImplementedError as e:
  print(e)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you're thinking about inheritance incorrectly. The base class is supposed to encapsulate everything that is shared across any of the subclasses. If something is not shared by all subclasses, by definition it is not part of the base class.

So your statement "if someone walks by it will look angry, and it will bark if it can" doesn't make sense to me. The "bark if it can" part is not shared across all subclasses, therefore it shouldn't be implemented in the base class.

What *should* happen is that the subclass that you want to bark *adds* this functionality to the `protect()` method. As in:

```
class Protector():
    def protect(self):
        self.lookangry()

class GermanShepherd(Protector):
    def protect(self):
        super().protect() # or super(GermanShepherd, self).protect() for Python 2
        self.bark()
```

This way all subclasses will `lookangry()`, but the subclasses which implement a `bark()` method will have it as part of the extended functionality of the superclass's `protect()` method.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about super. Your example isn't consistent with your last sentence though. It would be better to have `class Dog(Protector)` with `def protect` and `class GermanShepherd(Dog)` with `def bark`. And then you can do Husky, etc.. Can I edit your answer? Or does that belong in a new answer?

Comment: @Joooeey That design is fine, it just adds another layer of inheritance between `Protector` and `GermanShepherd`. I didn't put that in because you don't have multiple types of dogs in your example, and I think my answer should stand unless you edit your question to have that extra layer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one possibility:

Define a `bark` method that raises `NotImplementedError`, as in your option 4, but *don't* make it abstract.

This eliminates PyLint's complaint—and, more importantly, eliminates the legitimate problem it was complaining about.

---

As for your other options:

- `hasattr` is unnecessary LBYL, which is usually not Pythonic.
- The `except` problem can be handled by doing `bark = self.bark` inside a `try` block, then doing `bark()` if it passes. This is sometimes necessary, but the fact that it's a bit clumsy and hasn't been "fixed" should give you an idea of how often it's worth doing.
- Inspecting error messages is an anti-pattern. Anything that's not a separate, documented argument value is subject to change across Python versions and implementations. (Plus, what if `ManWithSidekick.bark()` does `self.sidekick.bark()`? How would you distinguish the `AttributeError` there?)

So, that leaves 2, 4.5, and 5.

I think in most cases, either 4.5 or 5 will be the right thing to do. The difference between them is not pragmatic, but conceptual: If a `ScaryCat` an animal that barks silently, use option 5; if not, then barking must be an optional part of protection that not all protectors do, in which case use option 4.5.

For this toy example, I think I'd use option 4.5. And I think that will be the case with most toy examples you come up with.

However, I suspect that most real-life examples will be pretty different:

- Most real-life examples won't need this deep hierarchy.
- Of those that do, usually either `bark` will either be implemented by all subclasses, or won't be called by the superclass.
- Of those that do need this, I think option 5 will usually fit. Sure, `bark`ing silently is not something a `ScaryCat` does, but `parse_frame` silently is something a `ProxyProtocol` does.
- And there are so few exceptions left after that, that it's hard to speak about them abstractly and generally.